# elasticsearch-kopf access to remote cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to connect to a remote elasticsearch cluster using the [kopf](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf) tool.
I don't have access to the cluster to install it as a plugin so I'm running it locally (using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`).

The cluster have shield installed with SSL and Authentication enabled.
I can connect using curl like so:
`curl -u user https://elastic-address.com:9200 -k`

But I cannot get kopf to access the cluster, I'm typing in the address:
`https://user:password@elastic-address.com:9200`

But this is what I get:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9999' is therefore not allowed access.`

So I install [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) plugin in my chrome and this is what I get:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:9999' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`

Is it even possible to connect to a remote cluster like this? if so, what do I need to do to make it work.

Comment: Which ES version are you using? There were some changes made in 5.0 and above to how site plugins are treated. Could you also post your CORS settings from elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: Elasricsearch 2.4.4